# How does the stat "- ## to all armor" work?

Tags: torchlight-2

Some weapons (and other items as I recall) have a stat that negatively affects enemy armor. For example, the [Quatermass and the Pit](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=6775361759627066447) legendary mace has a **-470 to all armor per hit** stat. But how does this work?

Let's suppose that I find a weapon that has -100 to all armor per hit, and I'm fighting an enemy with 500 total armor. Does each hit act as if the enemy only had 400 armor to begin with? Or does the enemy's armor degrade over time, to the point of being broken (e.g. after five hits with the aforementioned weapon, the enemy's armor is now 0)?

Comment: Hopefully their armor is degraded per-hit, it makes a lot of sense that repeated bashing destroys armor. Also, that could explain why shields sometimes break quickly without having any shield-breaking skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way armor per hit works is weird. What I have noticed monitoringthe combat log and procs for this effect is like this:

- A hit from such a weapon starts a 5 second proc on the target.
- Armor is subtracted from the target by the given amount
- If another hit lands within those 5 seconds the armor values fall further
- If you do not land a hit before the timer ends the armor is restored to their original values
- Armor values can reach a minimum of 0.

Comment: It's much simpler than you're making out. The debuff lasts for five seconds and stacks. That's it.

Comment: I have just articulated it here.