# -X to all armor per hit: Is this a global effect?

Tags: torchlight-2

If my pet has a collar with a "-X to all armor per hit" modifier and attacks an enemy, will I also see the benefit of that armor reduction during my attacks on the affected enemy or is this only for my pet?

For example, let's say an enemy has 50 armor.  My pet attacks and degrades the enemy armor by 10, taking its armor down to 40.  When I attack the same enemy without any modifiers, will its armor be 40 or 50 relative to my attacks?

This question also applies to online play.  If I degrade an enemy's armor with my attacks, will the other players also benefit from a lower enemy armor or am I the only one who benefits since I was the attacker?

Comment: I would imagine that an effect would only be global if it applies a status effect, otherwise it only applies for that particular attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned over [here in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86922/27134), the `-X armor per hit` effect applies a stacking debuff to the target with a five second, refreshable duration.

Due to this, the value of your targets' armor is being decreased directly, rather than being decreased under specific conditions (like if you use spell X, for instance). This means that any attacks you make, your pet makes, and your party makes will benefit from the effect.