# Does "-All Armor" create 1 debuff or 1 debuff for each armor type?

Tags: torchlight-2

We know from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86757/how-does-the-stat-to-all-armor-work) that skills/items with "-X All Armor" give a 5 second debuff on the monster that is refreshed if they are hit again within that 5 seconds and continues to stack all the way down to 0 armor.

However, if I am playing a Berserker with "-200 Physical Armor" per hit from the Shred Armor skill and my friend is playing an Engineer with "-100 All Armor" per hit, do they create separate debuffs (does the monster get 1 debuff saying -200 physical armor and 1 saying -100 all armor) from each hit?

Or does the "-X All Armor" create 5 debuffs (1 for each armor type) such that the "-X Physical Armor" stacks with the Shred Armor skill?

Answer (score 2):

The game has multiple debuffs for each debuff. For example, say you had a debuff that did -200 armor, and another that did -150 armor on the same attack. These would both apply a debuff, even though their effect and method is the same, stacking to -350.

You could even have multiple characters sporting the same exact debuff, and it would still stack, having 4 instances of the -200 and the -150, one for each player applying it.